# Select ComboBox AfterUpdate Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I am writing a script for a `UserForm` through which users can register to gain access to a Database. The `UserForm` has three fields, `Username`, `Password` and `Confirm Password`.

I have made it so that, after the user chooses a username, the script runs a `VLookUp` through the existing usernames to check if the username chosen already exists. If so, a `MsgBox` pops up, advising the selection of another username. In this case, all three fields of the `UserForm` are cleared. I would like to make the cursor be positioned in the `Username` field so that the user can straight away fill in a different username. However, after all fields are cleared, the `password` filed is the one selected instead. How can I solve this? Thank you for your help.

This is the code I have written:

```
Private Sub usernameinput_AfterUpdate()

Dim username As String
username = usernameinput.Text

Dim temp As String
On Error Resume Next
temp = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.usernameinput.Value, Range("Usernames"), 1, 0)

If username = temp Then
    MsgBox ("The username chosen already exists. Please chose a different username."), vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Existing Username"
    Err.Clear
    temp = ""
    Me.usernameinput.Value = ""
    Me.passwordinput.Value = ""
    Me.passwordconfirm.Value = ""
    Me.usernameinput.SetFocus
    On Error GoTo 0
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have handlers for any of those controls? Is it possible that the line for `SetFocus` is somehow skipped by some error in the code? What happens if you out a breakpoint on that line then continue step-by-step?

Comment: The line is not skipped. I have ran the code step by step and the `SetFocus` line functions but after  the `End Sub`, the `Password` field gets selected.

Answer (score 1):

you could act like follows:

in your UserForm code pane:

- declare a userform scoped variable

  ```
  Dim reset As Boolean
  ```
- insert this Sub

  ```
  Private Sub HandleReset()
      If reset Then
          Me.usernameinput.SetFocus
          reset = False
      End If
  End Sub
  ```
- add all other UserForm controls `Enter` event handler to call `HandleReset()` like follows:

  ```
  Private Sub passwordconfirm_Enter()
      HandleReset
  End Sub

  Private Sub passwordinput_Enter()
      HandleReset
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: I'm going to try this. Thank you.

Comment: @franciscofcosta, did you get through it?